# Html5 Canvases Have Max Size - What about Images?

Tags: html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

Html canvases have max sizes depending on device/browser. Eg some mobiles have roughly a 1000x1000 canvas max. What about images stored in memory? Can these be up to the ram of the phone/pc? Can you 'drawImage' large images to these 1000x1000 canvases where it does auto-cropping? (I don't have a phone to test this even for a specific device.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max size of an image object is probably browser or memory dependent.

**More to your question...**

The image object you draw into the canvas can be larger than the canvas.

This causes the canvas to become a "viewport" into the image.

For example:

- Your canvas is 1000x1000.
- Your image is 1500x1500.

If you do this then the image pixels will be cropped at x>1000 and y>1000.

```
// canvas shows image pixels from x=0-999 and y=0-999

drawImage(yourImage,0,0)
```

If you do this then image pixels will be cropped at x<200 & x>1200 and y<200 and y>1200.

```
// canvas shows image pixels from x=200-1999 and y=200-1999

drawImage(yourImage,-200,-200)
```

A mental exercise to see how this works is to imagine a piece of paper with a rectangle "viewport" cut from it.  Then move a larger-than-viewport image behind the paper.  Only a part of the image will only be visible through the viewport.  You can move the image and a different portion of the image will be revealed in the viewport.